# Core 2 WebApp intermittantly losses SDK Dependencies node

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I've been spinning up a Asp.net Core 2 WebApp and slowly adding services and class libraries to the solution. At some point a few days into the process the WebApp lost all references. As in, literally all. Note that the SDK node doesn't show:

[image: Missing SDK node]

and that all NuGet packages are unreferenced:

Answer (score 0):

1. I rolled back all changes to the branch and did not recover functionality.
2. I rolled back to an earlier commit.
3. I rebooted.
4. I started this message carefully documenting my situation with screen caps.
5. I opened the .csproj file to paste in proof that the nuget packages were present.
6. I noticed that a couple of the root files I'd been working on but had renamed to (e.g. 'bower.hld') thinking that as long as it's not .json it will be ignored. There were a couple of these 'commented out' files and looking in the .csproj file I noticed they were present.
7. I removed the files from the folder and the .csproj file.
8. The missing nodes were restored and lesson is learned.

---

> Leave the root of the project pristine.

---